# Split bar (Splitter) is not showing. Only on mouse hover the splitter is getting display

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, border-layout

I have an extJS border layout. My components are placed in all four region. Now i have given a split properties ( Also `split: true`) and splitter is working fine but splitter should show between the borders, and that is not happening.

**Splitter is showing only when i mouseover the border.** Here is my code. Any hack will be great.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
       renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
       height: 300,
       width: 600,
       layout:'border',

       defaults: {
         // collapsible: true,
          split: {
              size :10
          },
          bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
       },
       items: [{
          title: 'Panel1',
          region:'west',
          html: 'This is Panel 1'
       },{
          title: 'Panel2',
          region:'center',
          html: 'This is Panel 2'
       },{
          title: 'Panel3',
          region: 'south',
          html: 'This is Panel 3'
       },{
          title: 'Panel4',
          region: 'east',
          html: 'This is Panel 4'
       },{
          title: 'Panel5',
          region: 'north',
          html: 'This is Panel 5'
       }]
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast hack is to use "collapsible: true," this will show a small arrow on the boarders.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   height: 300,
   width: 600,
   layout:'border',

   defaults: {
     // collapsible: true,
      split: {
          size :10
      },
      collapsible: true,
      //collapseMode: 'mini',
      bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
   },
   items: [{
      title: 'Panel1',
      region:'west',
      html: 'This is Panel 1'
   },{
      title: 'Panel2',
      region:'center',
      html: 'This is Panel 2'
   },{
      title: 'Panel3',
      region: 'south',
      html: 'This is Panel 3'
   },{
      title: 'Panel4',
      region: 'east',
      html: 'This is Panel 4'
   },{
      title: 'Panel5',
      region: 'north',
      html: 'This is Panel 5'
   }]
});
```